# Sorting .csv file by column title

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way to sort a csv file by column header name (sort vertically) without loading the whole thing into memory? I tagged this as python because it is the language I am most familiar with, but any other way would be fine also. I am limited to doing this via commandline on a remote machine due to data protection rules.

Comment: Yes, but unless the file is huge, any way that doesn't involve loading it into memory will be slower than any way that does, so… are you sure you want that requirement?

Comment: No I don't think that is a necessary requirement. I should have sufficient RAM.

Comment: Also, is your "without loading it into memory" a constraint on _physical_ memory (in which case using `mmap` is an easy way around it), or on VM space (e.g., because you have to handle 12GB files on a 32-bit system, so `mmap` is useless)?

Comment: See [Guido's post](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html)

Comment: Also see [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) at Wikipedia—not Python-specific like Guido's post, but it describes various other algorithms/variations/optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any on-disk sorting algorithm is going to require more disk operations than just reading and writing once, and that I/O is likely to be your bottleneck. And it's going to more complicated as well. So, unless you really *can't* fit the file into memory, it will be a lot faster to do so, and a whole lot simpler.

But if you have to do this…

The standard on-disk sorting algorithm is a merge sort, similar to the familiar in-memory merge sort. It works like this:

Split the file into chunks that are big enough to fit into memory. You can do this iteratively/lazily, and easily: just read, say, 100MB at a time. Just make sure to rfind the last newline and hold everything after it over for the next chunk.

For each chunk, sort it in memory, and write the result to a temporary file. You can use the `csv` module, and the `sort` function with `key=itemgetter(colnum)`.

If you have, say, 10 or fewer chunks, just open all of the temporary files and merge them. Again, you can use the `csv` module, and `min` with the same key or `heapq.merge` with equivalent decorate-sort-undecorate.

If you have 10-100 chunks, merge groups of 10 into larger temp files, then merge the larger ones in exactly the same way. With 100-1000, or 1000-10000, etc., just keep doing the same thing recursively.

---

If you have a simple CSV file with no quoting/escaping, and you have either ASCII data, ASCII-superset data that you want to sort asciibetically, or ASCII-superset data that you want to sort according to `LC_COLLATE`, the POSIX [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) command does exactly what you're looking for, in the same way you'd probably build it yourself. Something like this:

```
sort -t, -k ${colnum},${colnum} -i infile.csv -o outfile.csv
```

If your data don't meet those requirements, you might be able to do a "decorate-sort-undecorate" three-pass solution. But at that point, it might be easier to switch to Python. Trying to figure out how to `sed` an arbitrary Excel CSV into something `sort` can handle and that can be reversed sounds like you'd waste more time debugging edge cases than you would writing the Python.

Comment: I get an error with that sort command ```-bash-3.2$ sort -t, -k ${colnum},${colnum} -i test.csv -o outfile.csv
sort: invalid number at field start: invalid count at start of `,'
```

Comment: @IanFiddes: I'm guessing you didn't define `colnum` as anything, so that ends up being `sort -t, -k , -i infile.csv -o outfile.csv`, so you're asking for a start column number of `,`, which isn't a number. You either need to do `colnum=2` (or whichever column number you want) before pasting that line, or substitute `2` for `${colnum}` manually.